# ANOVA of Returns and Volatilities forecast

Tags: anova, simulation, garch, conditional-expectation

In my GARCH(1,1) model simulations, I generated (based on two different distribution assumptions) returns and conditional volatilities for 8 stocks across 3 scenarios over a 20-day forecasting period. These scenarios include:

1. Basic Scenario: Comprising two matrices of size 20 x 8 x 1000 for simulated returns and volatilities (one for each of the two distribution assumptions).
2. Recession Scenario: Comprising two matrices of size 20 x 8 x 100 for simulated returns and volatilities.
3. Expansion Scenario: Comprising two matrices of size 20 x 8 x 500 for simulated returns and volatilities.

My objective is to compare the overall results of these scenarios in terms of expected returns and expected conditional volatilities. To achieve this, I'm considering conducting an ANOVA test (or seeking alternative suggestions). Here are my specific questions:

- Should I use two separate one-way ANOVA tests, one for expected returns and another for expected conditional volatilities, to compare the scenarios? Or would it be more appropriate to conduct a two-way ANOVA that includes both factors?
- Additionally, I'm curious about the role of the distribution assumption. Would it be meaningful to include it in the analysis using an N-way ANOVA, considering the two distribution assumptions as well?

I appreciate any insights or recommendations.